# Order and release NSArray in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsarray, release

I am trying to sort an array of countries. This way works, but I can't figure out the way to release tmpArray. How do I release it and is there a better way of doing this?

```
// PUT COUNTRIES IN ARRAY
NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Countries" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *tmpArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myFile]; 
tmpArray = [tmpArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];  
arrayCountries = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tmpArray] ;
   //   [tmpArray release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `-autorelease` the one you alloc/init'd (because you're losing your reference to it when you replace it with the sorted array) or use another variable like '`sortedTmpArray`'.

What you're currently doing is "create this object and assign it to `tmpArray`", then "create another array by filtering this one and assign it to `tmpArray`". At that point, you no longer have a pointer to the first array you created so there's no way to release it - it's leaked.

The solution is to place it in the autorelease pool when you create it or just use two separate pointers. Alternatively, you can create a mutable array the first time and use `-sortUsingDescriptors:` to sort it in place instead of creating two separate arrays.

Comment: Thanks! I put NSArray *tmpArray = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myFile] autorelease]; and now I don't get any warnings in the analyzer. Thanks Joshua.

Comment: Sure. Is "arrayCountries" an instance variable? If so, you could shorten it up by assigning the result of the sort to arrayCountires directly: arrayCountries = [[tmpArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] retain];   ...the retain is needed because -sortedArrayUsingSelector: returns an autoreleased array.

Comment: Cool. I tried that way first, but without the retain. With that it works fine and looks better. Again, thanks!